# Assistance with the "find" and "grep" command

Tags: find, grep

I'm looking for help with a one-liner that I can run from the Mac OS X terminal. I use MAMP for web development on my Mac. I have a lot of CakePHP projects in my "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs" directory. For the sake of simplicity, let's just say that I had two CakePHP projects and that this was the output of the `find /Applications/MAMP/htdocs -type d -iname Controller*` command:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_cake1.3_project/app/controllers
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_cake1.3_project/app/tests/cases/controllers
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_cake1.3_project/cake/console/templates/skel/controllers
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_cake1.3_project/cake/console/templates/skel/tests/cases/controllers
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_cake1.3_project/cake/libs/controller
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_cake1.3_project/cake/tests/cases/libs/controller
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_cake1.3_project/cake/tests/test_app/controllers
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_cake1.3_project/cake/tests/test_app/plugins/test_plugin/controllers
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_cake2_project/app/Controller
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_cake2_project/app/Test/Case/Controller
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_cake2_project/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/skel/Controller
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_cake2_project/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/skel/Test/Case/Controller
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_cake2_project/lib/Cake/Controller
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_cake2_project/lib/Cake/Test/Case/Controller
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_cake2_project/lib/Cake/Test/test_app/Controller
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_cake2_project/lib/Cake/Test/test_app/Plugin/TestPlugin/Controller
```

Now, sometimes I want to find a piece of code that I know I used in one of my CakePHP projects' controllers, but I can't remember which project it was, so I want to search all of them. I don't want to waste time searching in the "app/tests/cases/controllers" folder or any of the ones within "cake/", though. The `find /Applications/MAMP/htdocs -type d -iname Controller* | grep -i /app/Controller` command gives me the list of folders I want to search in:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_cake1.3_project/app/controllers
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_cake2_project/app/Controller
```

I just need to find a way to take that output, add a slash and asterisk (/*) to the end of each line, and pipe each line to the `grep -il "string to search for"` command. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solution 1**

maybe you want to check two options of find command: `(i)path` and `regex`
with them you could narrow your find result and pass found files to your `grep -il "searchString"` for example by `|xargs` . it looks like:

```
    find /Applications/MAMP/htdocs -type f -ipath "*/app/Controller/*.php" 
| xargs grep -il 'foo'
```

with `-regex` would be more flexiable.

**solution 2**

however if you really really want to :

> find a way to take that output, add a slash and asterisk (/*) to the
>   end of each line, and pipe each line to the grep -il "string to search
>   for" command.

(btw, here "pipe" won't work.)

you could do this:

```
find .(your original find).. |grep -i "/app/Controller" 
 |sed -r 's#^(.*)$#grep -il "foo" \1/*#g'|sh
```

the trick was done by the `sed....|sh`. the sed line will pick the result of your previous grep, add grep command and options :(`grep -il "foo"`) and append "`/*`" in order to construct a complete grep command. finally pipe to sh, to execute it.

Comment: I got both solutions to work! Thank you very much! To get the first solution to work with my specific needs, I had to replace `"*/app/Controller/*.php"` with `"*/app/Controller*"` (CakePHP < 2.0 is "controllers", CakePHP >= 2.0 is "Controller" without an "s"). To get the second solution to work with my specific needs, I had to replace `sed -r` with `sed -E`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
find /Applications/MAMP/htdocs -type d -iname Controller* 
-exec grep -il "string to search for" {} /;
```

Comment: The thing is I don't want to waste time searching in the "app/tests/cases/controllers" folder or any of the ones within "cake/". Thanks, though!